# MathJax Width too short for contents

Tags: css, mathjax

I have a piece of HTML that is being translated by MathJax, however MathJax is translating it in such a way that the width is too short and it is partially overlapping with some text.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a configuration in MathJax, or some piece of CSS code I can add so the text *" the same as"* will follow behind the *x* in span 65, instead of overlay.

The width tag of 2.008em seems to be the culprit. It is the length of *'1000'* without the *'x'*. But I can't say for sure that every *span.math* will need a margin in the end. I could reasonably say that any span.mi containing a span.mi would be a math symbol.

```
<span>
  <nobr>
    <span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-58" overflow="scroll" role="math" style="width: 2.126em; display: inline-block;">
      <span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 2.008em; height: 0px; font-size: 106%;">
        <span style="position: absolute; clip: rect(3.187em 1000em 4.189em -999.997em); top: -4.006em; left: 0.003em;">
          <span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-59">
            <span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-60">
              <span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-61">
                <span class="mn" id="MathJax-Span-62" style="font-family: MathJax_Main;">1000</span>
                <span class="mo" id="MathJax-Span-63"></span>
                <span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-64">
                  <span class="mi" id="MathJax-Span-65" style="font-family: MathJax_Math-italic;">x</span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
        <span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 4.012em;"></span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span style="border-left: 0.003em solid; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0.878em; vertical-align: -0.059em;"></span>
    </span>
  </nobr>
</span>
" the same as "
```

My current MathJax config appears as follows:

```
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      messageStyle: "none",
      jax: ["input/MathML", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/CommonHTML"],
      extensions: ["mml2jax.js", "CHTML-preview.js"],
      MathML: {
        useMathMLspacing: true
      },
      "HTML-CSS": {
        width: "container",
        scale: 100
      }
    });
```

Thanks,

Comment: The code shows that you are using MathJax's HTML-CSS output which is highly browser and OS dependent. It would be best to post a complete minimal example (e.g., using snippets, jsbin, codepen) using MathJax instead of copying output. While it could be a bug it looks more like the surrounding page CSS interferes with MathJax.

Comment: The 1000 is not the problem, as it is in the cliprect, which does not affect the width.  As peter says, without the input that produces this output, it is impossible to help you.